# Unable to parse build.framework.js.br

Tags: laravel, content-encoding

I want to run my webgl app in laravel but I get this error while running
How can I set the encoding into br?

```
If using custom web server, verify that web server is sending .br files with HTTP Response Header "Content-Encoding: br". Brotli compression may not be supported over HTTP connections. Migrate your server to use HTTPS.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to parse Build/build.framework.js.br](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72453065/unable-to-parse-build-build-framework-js-br)