# Unable to parse Build/build.framework.js.br

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl

We have uploaded unity application to hostinger.
When we launch index.html from app - getting error:

> Unable to parse Build/build.framework.js.br! This can happen if build compression was enabled but web server hosting the content was misconfigured to not serve the file with HTTP Response Header "Content-Encoding: br" present. Check browser Console and Devtools Network tab to debug.

Comment: Did you follow unity’s webserver instructions or assume to allow certain compressions?  This is common with the assumptions or older instructions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have compression enabled for you project. Go to Project Settings -> Player -> Publishing Settings on WebGL tab - and you can change your compression format to Gzip or disable it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Enable decompression fallback in publishing settings

[image: use decompression fallback in publishing settings]