# How do i merge unity web view in flutter app

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have a flutter app and i tried to merge unity web view in flutter app. how can i implement the unity web in flutter app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ['flutter_unity_widget_web 1.0.1'](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget_web/versions).

It's relatively simple to implement in your Flutter app. In the Unity project, go to Build settings before exporting in **Project Settings** -> **Player** -> **Publishing Settings** in the **WebGL** tab. Change the compression method to **Gzip** or disable it completely to avoid the error below:

> [Unable to parse Build/build.framework.js.br](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72453065/unable-to-parse-build-build-framework-js-br).